# Impossible to scroll Ipython (not notebook!) while producing output within tmux window

Tags: python, scroll, ipython, freeze, tmux

I have been trying to scroll the output of a script run via Ipython in a separate window/session created by tmux (off notebook, meaning that I am not using Ipython notebook as usual: I am just using Ipython). I see that, while the program is loading the output, I can’t scroll the window to see what has been published before, and can just visualize the latest results produced. Honestly, this problem comes totally unexpected because I usually use a notebook and have never encountered a similar issue. Could you help me please? Thanks in advance

Comment: If this is of some help, I want to clarify that I am running the ipython script on a new window created through tmux, so maybe that could be the root of the problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally found the answer to my problem right here https://superuser.com/questions/209437/how-do-i-scroll-in-tmux , it did not depend on Ipython but on tmux as I was suspecting. To scroll on tmux press ctrl+b and then [, so that you can enter the copy mode, and then use arrows or page up/down to scroll through the window, then press ctrl+c or Esc to quit the copy mode after finishing the desired scroll

Comment: I also add that to me it is also working the following series of commands: 1) tmux set -g mouse on 2)  open a new tmux window/session via tmux 3) exit and detach it via ctrl+b and d 4) re-enter via tmux attach-session -t sess_name (i.e. "0" if it is the first session created which is automatically renamed as 0) 5) shutting down via ctrl+b then & (and confirm yes) 6) open tmux again ... maybe it's a little bit counterintuitive but it's magically working and allows me to use mouse to scroll completely and with no issues

Answer (score -1):

Use threads for data processing, visualization, and gui interaction that is how you can avoid freez.

Comment: Hi @Kristan thanks a million for the hint, could you please post a link?? Many many thanks

Comment: Many thanks @Kristan I will have a look, in the meantime I can confirm that the problem is JUST within tmux window, as, out of that window, IPython has the standard behaviour of allowing to scroll the output with no issues at all

Comment: This answer has nothing to do with the original post at all.